# between html5 and C# web socket communication

Tags: c#, javascript, html, sockets, websocket

trying to send string data to windows c# application with this code;

```
try {
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.77:10048');
    ws.onopen = function () {
        ws.send("Sunucuya mesaj"); // I WANT TO SEND THIS MESSAGE TO SERVER!
    };

    ws.onclose = function () {
        alert('Bağlantı kapandı.');
    };
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

and trying to get data from windows c# application with this code;

```
static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
static private string guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8181));
serverSocket.Listen(128);
serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);


private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try
    {
        Socket client = null;
        string headerResponse = "";
        if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
        {
            client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
            var i = client.Receive(buffer);
            headerResponse = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0, i);
            // write received data to the console
            Console.WriteLine(headerResponse);

        }
        if (client != null)
        {

            var key = headerResponse.Replace("ey:", "`")
                      .Split('`')[1]                     // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ== \r\n .......
                      .Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0]  // dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
                      .Trim();

            // key should now equal dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
            var test1 = AcceptKey(ref key);

            var newLine = "\r\n";

            var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                 + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                 + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine
                 + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + test1 + newLine + newLine
                //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat" + newLine
                //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" + newLine
                 ;

            // which one should I use? none of them fires the onopen method
            client.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));

            var i = client.Receive(buffer); // wait for client to send a message

            // once the message is received decode it in different formats
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer).Substring(0, i));

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress enter to send data to client");
            Console.Read();

            var subA = SubArray<byte>(buffer, 0, i);
            client.Send(subA);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);//wait for message to be send


        }
    }
    catch (SocketException exception)
    {
        throw exception;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
        {
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
        }
    }
}
```

with this code i can communicate between client and server but i can't get **ws.send("Sunucuya mesaj");** message from server that send from client. **headerResponse = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0, i);** in this row you can see the header that is getting from server;

*GET / HTTP/1.1

Upgrade: websocket

Connection: Upgrade

Host: 192.168.1.77:8181

Origin: `http://localhost`

Sec-WebSocket-Key: dHI34r7feV/Ar4G0/fONCg==

Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame*

**How can i get data that is coming from client from server-side?**

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages between client and server are not plain text.  See the [data framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5) section of the protocol spec for details on how to encode/decode messages.

There are several liberally licensed open source C# servers you can take examples from.  Such as [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck/blob/master/src/Fleck/Handlers/Hybi13Handler.cs)

Comment: Ok, answer updated with a link to an example in another C# server